# Using vmware images with numa suppprt

Tags: linux, numa

I want to demonstrate Linux numa system with 2 virtual machine images running linux 
What is the best way and the correct distribution to use?

Comment: "What is the best way" - The one that works.  "the correct distribution to use?" - The distribution that satisfies all your requirements.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me more useful answer?

Comment: Can i do it with ubuntu?